# Keep laptop on after screen removal

Tags: laptop, display, centos, hibernate

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad x201 that has a broken screen, and I want to use it as a home server for my stuff. I made a minimal installation of CentOS 7 in it, and I then tried to power it on.

Because the screen was no longer working, I removed it (the laptop now looks like a very noisy keyboard), but for some reason that makes it go into hibernation mode. If I plug in an external monitor via VGA, it will stay on, but as soon as I unplug it, it hibernates. It's a headless installation so I don't know why it does that.

I have tried connecting back the original screen, but because it is broken it doesn't detect it and it still hibernates.

I know the OS fully boots because there is like a 15 second window before it hibernates where I can SSH into it.

How can I make it so that the OS will completely ignore the lack of a display and stay running?

Comment: @John the thing is that I want the machine to stay on without any screens, not even external. Basically like a normal headless server.

Comment: That gave me the idea of a VGA dummy plug. I searched a little and I found a way to fool the VGA into thinking there is something connected when there isn't, and since it uses only 3 resistors it's basically free. Here's the link for anyone that needs it: https://www.geeks3d.com/20091230/vga-hack-how-to-make-a-vga-dummy-plug/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [login manager config](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html) has various settings to change the triggers for ACPI events.

Changing `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` to `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` should lead to the wanted behaviour.